# Which children's television series from the 1980s featured a puppet who slid down a tube to its lair?

Tags: story-identification, tv

This children's television show was broadcast in Australia in the 1980s, most likely on the ABC, and featured children befriending a creature that might have looked a little like E.T. The children and the creature would slide down an organic-looking brown/green tube to get to the creature's lair, which was fairly small and may also have been the base of operations for the children and the creature - it may have had computers in it. I'm afraid that is the only clear memory I have of the show. I think the children were the main characters, along with the creature, but I can't remember anything that they did.

Comment: It wasn't [Oakie Doke](https://youtu.be/EbqaxWjIgOg?t=20) was it?

Comment: No tube sliding that I recall, but [Five Children and It](https://m.imdb.com/title/tt0245622/) had a creature that might match your description.

Comment: @Möoz No, it was much more organic and slimy-looking in my memory, and the sliding tube lead underground.

Comment: @HorusKol That doesn't look familiar, and it says it was released in 1991 in the UK and 1995 in Australia, whereas I would definitely have watched the show I'm trying to remember in the early to mid 1980s.

Comment: Unfortunately, there's not a lot else to go on. If you're definite about those details, update your question and delete the comments. And if you can remember anything else, then also please update. Otherwise, all I can suggest is looking through https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Australian_children%27s_television_series and seeing if anything there rings a bell.

Comment: Thanks very much for all these suggestions! I'm afraid none of them look like what I'm remembering - I will keep reading through the list suggested by @HorusKol and will add any extra details I can remember to my question.

Comment: From that list, I'm wondering about Nargun & The Stars - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PCHGgzV35lE - but I can't find any more footage that that short collection of clips.

Answer (score 6):

I wonder if you are thinking of the 1981 tv adaptation of "Under the Mountain"? The children, Rachel & Theo, don't befriend any alien creatures, rather they are trying to stop them from taking over New Zealand (and the rest of Earth).

There is a clip here that shows the Wilberforce's lair.  https://www.nzonscreen.com/title/under-the-mountain-episode-four-1981
They are giant slugs so their lair is very organic, and the children slide down into it.

The tv program (and 2009 film) are based on the book of the same title by Maurice Gee.

Comment: Wow, that it a lot scarier than the show I'm remembering :) The slide in my memory was short and brown/green. Thanks for trying!

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this is too obvious, but this made me think of [Fraggle Rock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraggle_Rock).  It is from the 1980s, was broadcast in Australia, and features an intro with puppet traveling down a tunnel to their lair.

There were also interactions between the Fraggle world and real humans, through the adventures of Traveling Matt, e.g.

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't look right :( The show I'm remembering was much smaller than Fraggle Rock, and I think the children were the main characters, along with the creature.